# is it possible to shuffle validation data using fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using Tensorflow model.fit_generator, we can set shuffle to True. The doc says that it will shuffle the training generator's data before each epoch.

Since I have alot of data, my goal is to validate on a sample of my validation data every 100 steps, so I set steps_per_epoch to 100 and using shuffle = True, I know that the 100 batches of training data will be randomly picked from the training data for every epoch.

Is there a way to acheive the same with my validation data ? I.e, everytime we validate, pick 50 batches randomly from all the validation data

```
traindata = 200_000
validation data = 40_000
batch_size = 32

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    epochs=20,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[tensorboard, early_stopping, mcp_save],
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=50,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=4,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    shuffle=True,
)
```

```
def make_train_generator():
    train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train',
                                                        target_size=(32, 64), 
                                                        class_mode='binary', 
                                                        batch_size=32)
    return train_generator

def make_test_generator():
    test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/test',
                                                        target_size=(32, 64), 
                                                        class_mode='binary', 
                                                        batch_size=32)
    return test_generator
```

Comment: You can do it inside your `test_generator`. It would help if you can provide the code for `test_generator`.

Comment: added code of the generators, I think you are right, I can set shuffle directly in the generator